# Difference between 'evaluation' and 'evaluation-criteria' tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The [evaluation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) and [evaluation-criteria](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-criteria) tags seem extremely similar to me.

[evaluation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) is used in 30 questions. Its description is

> Questions relating to academic evaluation and the process of evaluation.

[evaluation-criteria](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-criteria) is used in 18 questions. Its description is

> How to appraise or prepare for the appraisal of/by mentors, students, grants, applications, or work performance.

Can we merge these two tags or just drop one? They seem to cover the same area and having two is redundant.